# How to know caret coordinates (not position) in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, caret

I would like to draw autocomplete-like drop-down box near caret in JavaFX controls like [`TextField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextField.html) and [`TextArea`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextArea.html).

Is it possible to know double numeric coordinates of the caret in node coordinate system?

Comment: Just to be sure, this isn't what you're looking for [Ambior answer](https://github.com/TomasMikula/RichTextFX/issues/30) ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `inputMethodRequests` property to retrieve the position. You can specify a index relative to the start of the selection to get the screen coordinates for the char.

```
private static ContextMenu createMenu(String... text) {
    ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu();
    EventHandler<ActionEvent> handler = evt -> {
        TextInputControl control = (TextInputControl) menu.getUserData();
        String t = ((MenuItem) evt.getSource()).getText();
        control.replaceSelection(t);
    };
    for (String s : text) {
        MenuItem item = new MenuItem(s);
        item.setOnAction(handler);
        menu.getItems().add(item);
    }
    return menu;
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    ContextMenu menu = createMenu("Hello World", "42", "foo", "bar");
    TextArea textArea = new TextArea();

    TextField textField = new TextField();

    VBox root = new VBox(textArea, textField);
    root.setPadding(new Insets(10));

    EventHandler<KeyEvent> handler = evt -> {
        if (evt.isControlDown() && evt.getCode() == KeyCode.SPACE) {
            evt.consume();
            TextInputControl control = (TextInputControl) evt.getSource();
            Point2D pos = control.getInputMethodRequests().getTextLocation(0);
            menu.setUserData(control);
            menu.show(control, pos.getX(), pos.getY());
            menu.requestFocus();
        }
    };

    textArea.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, handler);
    textField.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, handler);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```